# Esconder h4 sem link e mostrar h4 com link

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma div `.cx-single` e nela há um `<h4>`, gostaria de exibir esse `<h4>` somente quando ele tiver um link. Como faço isso em jQuery?

Comment: Link? Em qual sentido? Anchor <a> ou uma URL?

Comment: @nicematt é uma tag <a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso apenas com uma linha de código utilizando o [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) para detetar se o elemento `h4` tem um link/tag (`<a>`), e deixar ele escondido já previamente com um `display:none;` no código CSS da seguinte forma:

```js
$('.cx-single h4').has('a').css('display', 'block');
```

```css
.cx-single h4 a.link {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cx-single">
  <h4><a class="link">Insira o Link Aqui</a></h4>
  <h4>Insira o Link Aqui</h4>
</div>
```

Como podes ver o segundo link não é exibido por não conter nenhum elemento com a tag `<a>`